# Поиск куска кода в самом документе-html

Tags: html, javascript

Доброго времени суток! 
Возникла такая задачка, сделать поиск фрагмента кода в Html-странице по самому себе.
То есть допустим где-то в коде будет конструкция такая `<!-- JavaScriptText: Привет, пользователь! -->` И надо по нажатию кнопки к примеру, вызвать Alert в котором будет указан текст найденный между конструкцией комментариев, тоесть: "Привет, пользователь!". Тоесть html-странице надо проанализировать свое содержимое и найти конструкцию для вывода в алерт. Это сложно сделать, с учетом того что нет привязки к конкретному имени файла-html?

Comment: Комментарии тоже являются частью HTML-документа. По идее попробуйте поискать тег !-- или --

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Документация по типам DOM элементов](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodetype.asp)**
Пример на **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/yyL4f/3/)**

**html**

```
<button id="magician">Сим-салабим-ахалай-махалай</button>
<!-- JavaScriptText: Привет, пользователь! -->
<!-- Я просто комментарий -->
```

**javascript**

```
var button = document.getElementById('magician'), //Кнопка
    nodes = document.body.childNodes; //Все элементы внутри тэга body

button.onclick = function () {    
    var i = 0,
        nodes_total = nodes.length;

    //Перебираем все элементы
    for (i = 0; i<nodes_total; ++i) {    
        //Если комментарий
        if (nodes[i].nodeType === 8) {
            var mark = nodes[i].nodeValue.trim().substr(0, 16), //Метка
                text = nodes[i].nodeValue.trim().substr(16); //Текст без метки
            //Если метка в комментарии найдена
            if (mark === 'JavaScriptText: ') {                    
                alert(text);
            }
        }        
    }
};
```

**Вывод:**

```
Привет, пользователь!
```

Comment: Неплохой пример! Но тут JQuery используется... Это легко. Мне без него надо обойтись, только на чистом JavaScript'е.

Comment: @IntegralAL, обновил ответ, теперь решение написано на чистом javascript.

Comment: Спасибо, кратко и функционально!

Answer (score 3):

На чистом JavaScript с использованием регулярных выражений: [source](http://jsfiddle.net/pmt8B/)

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <!-- JavaScriptText: First  -->
    <!-- JavaScriptText: Second  -->
    <div id="comments"></div>
    <!-- JavaScriptText: Third  -->
</body>
```

**JavaŠcript**

```
var markup = document.documentElement.innerHTML
var regexp = /<!--\sJavaScriptText:([\s\S]*?)-->/gim
var match = regexp.exec(markup)
var comments = ''

while (match != null) {
    comments += match[1].trim() + '<br/>'
    match = regexp.exec(markup)
}

document.getElementById('comments').innerHTML = comments
```

**Результат**

```
First
Second
Third
```

Comment: Но зачем использовать регулярные выражения для поиска комментариев, когда для комментариев есть отдельный nodeType?  
Как говорится: _Если у вас была одна проблема, и вы решили использовать регулярные выражения, то теперь у вас есть две проблемы_

Comment: Как Я понимаю, решение требует выбирать не все комменты, а только с определенной конструкцией, например с приставкой "JavaScriptText:". Можно перебирать все ноды, а можно пройтись регуляркой. Кому как проще.
Регулярные выражения - такой же функциональный элемент, как и многие другие. Не вижу особых проблем в их использовании при необходимости.

Comment: @uzumaxy, все любят regexp, но не все любят забивать гвозди орбитальным телескопом. 
Конкретика простая - парсер на regexp (особенно не-PCRE, как в js) если и не невозможен, то уж точно очень и очень сложен. например, в вашем коде:


    //..
    // получаем строки вида <!-- JavaScriptText:
    var regexp = /<!--\sJavaScriptText:([\s\S]*?)-->/gim
    //...

к тому-же документ может быть реально большим.

Comment: regex способные представить любой контекстно-свободный язык, почему же парсинг невозможен? Очень сложен? Соглашусь, иногда да, в таком случае регулярки лучше не использовать, при наличии альтернативны.

Comment: Вот Вам конкретный пример: найти комментарии с заданной конструкцией. Разве приведенное в ответе регулярное выражение выглядит страшным или хоть немного похоже на телескоп? Более того, этот способ решения задачи есть более универсальным. Если изменить шаблон комментов для поиска с "JavaScriptText: Привет, пользователь!" на "JavaScriptText BEGIN: Привет, пользователь! END", то скрипт с регулярками потребует только изменения переменной "regexp", в то время как вариант с перебором НОДов необходимо будет переделывать более значительно.

Comment: я же привел контр-пример, когда код просто ошибется, естественно можно и это учесть и ещё тысячу контрпримеров, поэтому и говорят - не надо тут регексп на весь документ.

Answer (score 2):

Но зачем, в этом нет смысла. Нужные вам данные вы можете разместить на странице в виде JS/JSON вставок, например [так](http://jsfiddle.net/2yV53/), или [так](http://jsfiddle.net/2yV53/1/).

Comment: Ну это не годится. Тут просто фактически на вывод подаем значение переменной или элемента массива. А надо открыть саму себя html-страницу прочитать от начала до конца и найти в тексте совпадения с маской поиска, после которого идет само сообщение. В данном случае после JavaScriptText: идет само сообщение. Их может быть несколько на странице и с разными сообщениями.

Comment: И что? Зачем эту информацию хранить в dom-коментах? Они не для этого. Вы точно также можете пройтись по массиву значений и по определенной маске найти нужный текст. Если это ради фана или практики, то [делается подобное просто][1]. Но в качестве решения задачи, никуда не годится. 

[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/2yV53/2/

Comment: Это так сказали просто, хотя это согласен нецелесообразно. Спасибо за ответ!